# How to stop animation after some interval in cocos2d-iphone?

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone

Code ::

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(food.sprite.boundingBox, playerRect)) {
    [food.sprite stopAllActions]; 

    [walkAnimFrames addObject: [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:

    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"newpackman2.png", 0]]];

    [walkAnimFrames addObject: [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:

    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"newpackman3.png", 1]]];

    walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.2f];

    self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];

    self.walkAction.tag = 1;
    [chef runAction:_walkAction];
}
```

It works fine,it starts animation when object is collided with chef but runs continuously.

I want to stop animation after 3-4 seconds.
I have used **`[sprite stopActionByTag:1]`** but, it doesn't work for me, once it is start it doesn't pause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can create action block which stops all animations and call there `stopAllActions` method

```
CCSprite *sprite = ...;

CCCallBlock *block = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
            [sprite stopAllActions];
        }];
```

and use CCDelayTime for some delay

```
CCDelayTime *time = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:4];


[sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:time, block, nil]];
```

Comment: Wow,,it works like a charm but it stops my other action like   [chef runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                               [CCSequence actions:
                                [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.0 position:ccp(0,240)],
                                [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.0 position:ccp(0,-240)], nil]]];  i want to continue this action after my animation stops.

Comment: I remember i had some problems with stoping. Than you do not need to stop all actions. Try to set tags to all your animations CCMoveBy , CCMoveBy, CCSequence, CCRepeatForever . And in this block to stop them using tag.

Comment: Ahhh,it works fine...Thanks !! I want to Vote Up but doesn't have enough reputation..

Answer (score 0):

In Cocos2d, stopAllActions stops all actions added to same node. If not stops it means you are referring wrong node. Make sure you called stopAllActions on right sprite.

Answer (score 0):

```
CCDelayTime *time = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:10];// After 10 mile seconds

[sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:time, block, nil]];
```